# How to use a variable value from one component to another?

Tags: angular

I have a list, on selecting a list item, I am calling `onSelect()`.

In `onSelect()`, I am placing the selected value in a variable selectedHero. How can use this value in selectedHero variable in other components. My code as mentioned below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { name: 'STWX1' },
    { name: 'STWX2' },
    { name: 'STWX3' },
    { name: 'STWX4' }
];

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div style="display: inline-block; width = 200px; ">
            <ul class="heroes">
                <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)"
                    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
                     <p>{{hero.name}}</p>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </div>'
   ,
   styles: [...]
})

export class AppComponent  {
 public showStyle: boolean = false;

    name = 'Angular1';
    testRequestId = '3224';
    heroes = HEROES;
    selectedHero: Hero;

    goToDivClick() {
        return HEROES;
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }
}
```

How can I use this.selectedHero value in other components.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the pass value using the **directive [valueToPass]="valuepassed"** and receive it using **@Input() valueToPass** decorator.

Or you can use a service since a single service instance is injected using a provider thus you can set some value inside that service and that value can be accessed in another component inside same module

Answer (score 0):

It depends where are the other components to which you want to pass the value. If they are children of the mentioned component, then you can use [@Input()](http://learnangular2.com/inputs/)  decorator. In other cases, you have to use services.